# Data cleaning using grepl for [:alpha:]:[:punct:]

Tags: r, data-cleaning, grepl

just using grepl wrong. need to combine [:alpha:]: [:punct:]: in grepl for finding / droping rows with [:alpha:] [:punct:]. dput data provided. need to find punct and alpha data to drop roles and replace with NA or NaN. how to combine grepl with [:alpha:] [:punct:] in R language?

```
grepl("[:alpha:]:[:punct:]:",df$Incoming.Examinations)
dput(df$Incoming.Examinations)

dput(abberville_LA$Incoming.Examinations)
c("698", "xx?*&?/..", "1934", "2294", "962", "724", "4978", 
"99999999", "4841", "Closed for Holidays", "*", "775", "634", "1276", "1320", 
"3455", "886", "1973", "2739", "311", "999999999", "939", "545", 
"3946", "2239", "1041", "411", "3258", "entered by J.f. williams", 
"1115", "*", "4729", "5008", "*", "*", "1011", "1065", "2262", 
"3459", "596", "776", "1866", "5000", "1578", "393", "*", "*", 
"875", "2772", "997", "664", "680", "4351", "1205", "732")
```

Comment: Do you need `grepl("[[:alpha:]][[:punct:]]", df$Incoming.Examinations)`  Please show the expected output for the example

Comment: I need to include "Closed for Holidays", "*" with grepl also.

Comment: In that case, the condition in the pattern should be changed with `|`

Comment: also it missed "entered by J.f. williams" on the grepl

Comment: It is not missing that `v1[grepl("[[:alpha:]][[:punct:]]", v1)]#
[1] "xx?*&?/.."                "entered by J.f. williams"`

Comment: the | helped me, grepl("[[:alpha:]] | [[:punct:]]" for strings. this is a numeric field

Comment: Please check the solution i posted below.  I think that is what you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intention is to convert the non-numeric elements to NA

```
as.numeric(v1)
```

will automatically convert all other elements to NA.

But if we need to use `grepl()`, match one or more digits (`[0-9]+`) from start (`^`) to end (`$`) of the string and negate (`!`)

```
v1[!grepl("^[0-9]+$", v1)] <- NA
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("698", "xx?*&?/..", "1934", "2294", "962", "724", "4978", "99999999", 
"4841", "Closed for Holidays", "*", "775", "634", "1276", "1320", 
"3455", "886", "1973", "2739", "311", "999999999", "939", "545", 
"3946", "2239", "1041", "411", "3258", "entered by J.f. williams", 
"1115", "*", "4729", "5008", "*", "*", "1011", "1065", "2262", 
"3459", "596", "776", "1866", "5000", "1578", "393", "*", "*", 
"875", "2772", "997", "664", "680", "4351", "1205", "732")
```

Comment: perfect, I forgot the <- pipe for NA assignment. too many things to do.